# how to handle server scalability

Tags: ubuntu, centos, centos5

I purchased a server running under centos6 and calculate its dimensions and scalability for a webproject that will handle a lot of users in a future. However, when server will reach its maximum limitations, another one will be purchased but, how to handle it? Which utilities are used to control it? Any starting point would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you asking how you'd buy a bigger server?

Comment: I am asking about how to handle multiple servers

Answer (score 0):

When one server will be saturated, you will either need to do caching or load-balancing between your two (or more) servers (or both caching and load-balancing).

There are dedicated devices to do that, as well as specialized software.

I am currently working on such a (software) solution for our own needs, adapting our Web server to support both caching and load-balancing, mainly for PHP and Java applications.

The choice is a matter of budget and other (technical) constraints so it cannot be discussed without much more knowledge about your project.